# Is this a good design?

Tags: c++, api, user-interface

Right now my gui is abstract and basically has a Bitmap class which holds a void* to the native bitmap type. The way it works is I have an abstract bitmap loader which returns a void pointer to the image data given a path string. the loader is a static pointer in the Bitmap data type and is set by the user for whatever backend used. The Graphics class is abstract and a pointer to it is asked for by the Gui class. When the backend for the Graphics class draws an image it does something like this:

```
void Allegro5GraphicsManager::drawImage( const Bitmap &bmp,
                                            const Point &position,
                                            const Point &regionStart,
                                            const Dimension &regionSize,
                                            const float &opacity /*= 1.0f*/ )
{
    al_draw_tinted_bitmap_region((ALLEGRO_BITMAP*)bmp.getBitmap(),
        al_map_rgba_f(opacity,opacity,opacity,opacity),
        regionStart.getX(),regionStart.getY(),
        regionSize.getWidth(),regionSize.getHeight(),
        position.getX() + getOffset().getX(),position.getY() + getOffset().getY(), 0);
}
```

So as you can see it mearly type casts the void* to what it needs.

The problem is I hear void*s are not a good idea in C++.

The other solution I thought of is for something like Allegro5Bitmap which would inherit from Bitmap.

The problem I had with this method was that the user would then have to plaster Allegro5Bitmap all over their code. And this defeats the concept of my API which is for all code written to be portable to other backends like sdl, etc, by simply initializing the Gui class with sdl manager pointers.

What could I do?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't this go in codereview.stackexchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is bad design. void* is what you definitely want to get rid of in C++.

It is not fully clear to me what problem you are trying to solve. Is it only about abstracting I/O of images or also drawing of them?

the typical solution to the I/O problem is to have ImageReader/ImageWriter abstract classes. Then their implementations are based on image type or I/O backend. These classes are basically factories for Image objects.

What you are handling in your code afterwards is still a generic Image (btw. you know that a "bitmap" actually is a black+white image?).

*Note:* Even if you need to have different types of Image objects (derivations), the factory is the typical pattern to resolve your issue while staying generic in your other code. You obtain an Image object from the factory, that in fact is an AllegroImage or whatever other type. You only call the base class methods on the Image so you don't care.

Comment: Which one is a bad design? The first, second or both?

Comment: Your void* is bad design. With your second approach, your assumption is wrong that the user would have to refrain from operating on the base class.

Comment: Ok I'll make a factory. Thanks